# Взять все элементы с атрибутом

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack, anglesharp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть на сайте кучу `div` которые имеют атрибут `data-href`.
Мне нужно взять именно эти `div` и вытянуть с них значение атрибута.
Как ни пробовал, он не видит их, вот мой код:

```
var all_web = document.QuerySelectorAll("div[data-href]");
foreach (var el_web in all_web)
            {Console.WriteLine(el_web.GetAttribute("data-href").ToString());}
```

и через Where

```
var all_web = document.QuerySelectorAll("div").Where(x=>x.HasAttribute("data-href"));
foreach (var el_web in all_web)
            {Console.WriteLine(el_web.GetAttribute("data-href").ToString());}
```

div селектор самого сайта:

```
<div data-href="//aliexpress.ru/item/*******.html.../div>
```

Я беру html с помощью httpclient, и дальше по стандарту

```
string allhtml = await client.GetStringAsync("https://aliexpress.ru/......./");
 var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss(); 
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config); //description item_table-description  
IDocument document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(allhtml))
```

Comment: Это возможно посредством рекурсивного поиска по нодам. Еще вроде плагины есть, которые позволяют выполнять что-то типа jQuery запросов. Почему не работает QuerySelector - пока не понятно, но я им не пользовался.

Comment: Покажите, как вы загружаете строку в документ.

Comment: Я имею в виду не строку текста, а тип данных string. Добавьте этот код в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проанализировав страницу по вашей ссылке, я не увидел ни одного тега `div` с требуемым аттрибутом `data-href`.

Я использовал:

- HtmlAgilityPack 1.11.23
- Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack 1.2.1

Попробовал выдачу для `a[data-href]`, всё заработало.

```csharp
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string page = client.GetStringAsync("https://aliexpress.ru/store/<censored>").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml(page);
    HtmlNode document = html.DocumentNode;
    IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes = document.QuerySelectorAll("a[data-href]");
    foreach (HtmlNode el_web in nodes)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(el_web.Attributes["data-href"].Value); 
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

*(Простите, не стал заморачиваться с асинхронностью)*

Возможно, вы не видите нужных тегов потому, что их рендерит в обычном браузере JavaScript. Поэтому получить их напрямую не получится. Нужно проанализировать, куда еще браузер шлет запрос, и из какого именно ответа прилетают нужные вам данные. Брать эти правила и пробовать по ним слать запросы на алик и парсить данные, оттуда полученные.

Comment: Я прикрепил скриншот, где `div` с `data-href`

Comment: @PrinceTag здесь видимо другая проблема, эти divы приезжают не в основном коде страницы, а в ajax запросе от яваскрпта, сейчас попробую найти, откуда.

Comment: @PrinceTag да, все верно, они приезжают в [jsonp](https://gpsfront.aliexpress.ru/getI2iRecommendingResults.do?scenario=pcStoreJustForYou&storeId=516307&offset=1&limit=25&callback=jsonp_1587320846859_5190) ответе из API, ведь это вам надо? То есть, из айдишника страницы можно сгенерить подобный запрос, ответ прилетит в jsonp формате, из него можно достать json и распарсить как json.

Comment: Есть гайды, или ссылки, как можно отвечать из API

Comment: @PrinceTag просто посмотрите сетевой лог страницы, посмотрите в ссылку из предыдущего ответа, в нее просто можно подставить айдишник нужной страницы и другие параметры. последний параметр callback может иметь любое значение, сервер просто его вернет в самом начале ответа, например `callback=resp`

Comment: @PrinceTag просто обратите внимание на ссылки, начинающиеся с `https://gpsfront.aliexpress.ru/getI2iRecommendingResults.do`. Логически поразмыслив, легко уловить, как ими пользоваться, зная только айдишник страницы.

Comment: @PrinceTag я добавли рекомендации в ответ. Если он вас устраивает, прошу его принять. Если же появился другой вопрос, создайте его отдельно на StackOverflow.

Comment: Все, я понял про что вы, тут get запрос, который возвращает json. Спасибо за ответ)